# Repository for editor book classes?

Tags: document-classes, sv-classes

Is there any place on the web where I can find legacy/public domain classes from book editors? For instance, I really like the style of [this book](https://books.google.be/books?id=Oh4DCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Design%20of%20Low-Voltage,%20Low-Power%20CMOS%20Operational%20Amplifier%20Cells%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAnI6SpdvaAhXFZVAKHcUADvgQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) but the current Springer book class (svmono.cls) doesn't produce this type of output anymore. Any ideas of where I could find the class used for that book (or any other editor book classes, for that matter)?

Thanks for any help!
Regards, Jorge.

Comment: There are publishers that make their classes available at their sites. Other just don't. Some of those are easy to reproduce. It depends on your motivation, and your reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Joseph. Do you know of any book classes openly available from publishers?

Comment: you imply that the svmono has changed but is it clear that the book was set with a springer class originally (it says it was published by Kluwer originally) or that it was set by TeX?

Comment: The only one I know that faithfully reproduces the final output is from De Gruyter: https://www.degruyter.com/dg/page/production-for-authors/herstellung. You should also consider taking a look at classes like caesar, tufte-book and octavo, among others. It all depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks David and Joseph. I'll take a look to those classes. W.r.t to Kluwer, I was only able to found one ("kluwer.cls") but it's for journal articles, not books.

Comment: A horrible look of mathematical expressions in this book suggests that it is not LaTeX based.